# Gradle sync taking a long time to complete resolving dependencies

Tags: android, gradle

My android studio project takes too long to sync, over 15 minutes. It is always trying to resolve dependencies like the ones below.

[image]

[image]

It takes above 15 minutes to complete the sync and about 10 - 15 minutes to build

I have offline mode enabled

I have Gradle 4.4

In my project build gradle file:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.3.1'
```

Comment: Try to File-Invalidate caches and restart, enable online mode, and check your CPU, DISK usage, as well the connection speed.

Comment: @Skenia i just tried invalidating the cache...android studio restarted and it is still doing the same thing. I have another project that does not do this when syncing and it takes seconds to build as well. the difference is that the other project has an old version of gradle and also uses and old version of google services in its project gradle file. my android studio version is 3.0

Comment: Upload your project to github so others can check too

Comment: It's an absolute joke, M1 Mac running native M1 Android Studio, still takes 20 minutes on a 100/40 up/down Mb/s internet connection. Does anybody know how I can make it download things in parallel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was a bunch of viruses on my system. After running a boot time scan on my system i ran the sync and now its back to taking a minute to run.

Answer (score 0):

Have you check your internet connection ? Maybe it's about connection matter

Comment: Hi @Beliga44, this does not give an answer to the question, could you please move it in the comments?

Comment: its not my internet connection. that is fine. been having  this problem for over a day.